# How can I create .Net extension methods by C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, extension-methods

In C#, extension methods can be created by

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static ReturnType MyExt(this ExtType ext) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since all of my library are written in C++/CLI, I would like to create the .net extension methods also in C++/CLI (in order to have one DLL instead of two). I've tried the following code

```
static public ref class MyExtensions {
public:
    static ReturnType^ MyExt(this ExtType ^ext) {
        ...
    }
};
```

But the compiler can not recognize keyword 'this' in the first argument.

```
error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
```

Is there some way to create the extension method in C++/CLI ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just have to decorate the method and the containing class with [ExtensionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx):

```
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
...

[ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class MyExtensions abstract sealed {
    public:        
        [ExtensionAttribute]
        static ReturnType MyExt(ExtType ^ext) {
            ...
        }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the namespace too - so many times people (who are otherwise being helpful) miss this.

Comment: You should also mark the assembly with [assembly: ExtensionAttribute]. Personally I would add this to AssemblyInfo.cpp.